# 100% footer with no divs

Tags: html, css

I'm making a template based on not using `DIVs`, but I am having trouble with the footer. I was wondering if I could have a 100% width footer (a bit like stackoverflow) that actually sticks to the bottom, wont fix or hide overflow when more content is added and maintains the background colours.

Is this possible?

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dougsterb/wk8Jf/).

```css
header, article {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:500px
}
html, body {
    height:100%
}
body {
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0
}
header, article, section {
    text-align:left;
    font:normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:black
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:grey
}
footer p {
    text-align:left;
    font:normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:white
}
footer article {
    height:50px;
    width:100%
}
footer section {
    background:black;
    height:50px;
    width:100%
}
footer section p {
    text-align:left;
    font:normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:white
}
header, article {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:500px
}
html, body {
    height:100%
}
body {
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0
}
header, article, section {
    text-align:left;
    font:normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:black
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:grey
}
footer p {
    text-align:left;
    font:normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:white
}
footer article {
    height:50px;
    width:100%
}
footer section {
    background:black;
    height:50px;
    width:100%
}
footer section p {
    text-align:left;
    font:normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:white
}
```

Comment: "Pure CSS Sticky Footer" might be helpful: http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: Please check the following update of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wk8Jf/2/

Comment: By the way, what is the point of having no divs in the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an example where the footer is `fixed` and use body:after to add padding to make it scrollable.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wk8Jf/3/

or if you want to it scroll with the page:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wk8Jf/5/

Comment: **Thank you** Mr. Mckee for fixing the footer.

Answer (score 0):

The position absolute on the  element seems to be the problem.

Comment: That doesn't keep the footer pegged to the bottom of the window.

Comment: In your fiddle, the footer hides the overflow of the text. I'm not sure you can meet all the requirements of the question without javascript.